# Bing Maps - How to do a search on a specific area/viewport?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am currently using Bing maps and I want to search for a set of restaurants within a particular area or an address. I see a property called as Radius for SearchOptions, however I do not have a center property inorder to clearly specify my area of interest.

Once I have this, I will then use the SearchService SOAP implementation to get the desired the output. I search extensively the documentation in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966867), but could not figure any.

Is this possible at all in Bing maps ? If not, what would be the closest/nearest workaround to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the current viewport at any point in time via the [BoundingRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.boundingrectangle) property. So to allow the user to search for restaurants in the currently visible map area, retrieve the bounding rectangle and send it to your search API.